# Failed to load graph (chartjs) from ajax returned JSON

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, chart.js

I am using chartjs library for chart generation in html. My HTML, jQuery and PHP are OK, the problem is, when I try to push JSON generated with PHP with ajax call and call the function for graph generation - i have an error (invalid character in JSON). So my code looks like this:

PHP:

```
$queryPortals = "SELECT description,count(*) AS count FROM portals WHERE ".$portals." AND id<900 GROUP BY description";
$resultPortals = mysqli_query($conn,$queryPortals);
while ($ar = mysqli_fetch_array($resultPortals)) {
    $rows[] = "{category: '".$ar['description']."', value: ".$ar['count']."}";
}
echo json_encode($rows,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

This code returns this JSON:

```
[
    "{category: 'Blog', value: 1}",
    "{category: 'Portal', value: 1}"
]
```

My ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'class/portalAnalysisGetGraphs.php',
    data: 'portals='+portals,
    success: function(html){
        drawPie(html);
    }
});
```

My drawPie function looks like this:

```
function drawPie(html)
    {
    $("#chartContainer").dxPieChart({
        dataSource: html,
        series: {
            argumentField: 'category',
        valueField: 'value',
            label: {
                visible: true,
                connector: {
                    visible: true
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            percentPrecision: 2,
            customizeText: function (value) {
                return value.percentText;
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Portal types'
        },
        legend: {
            horizontalAlignment: 'center',
            verticalAlignment: 'bottom'
        }
    });
};
```

There is an error in parsing JSON. I've tried to build JSON in PHP withous double quotes, I tried javascript functzion JSON_parse(html) - no luck.

When I put data directly to drawPie function, then it's ok. Direct data input example:

```
var html= [
    {category: 'Blog', value: 1},
    {category: 'Portals', value: 1}                                                     
];
```

Please help...

Comment: well why don't you do a console.log of what you are trying to draw and see if it's in the right format?

Comment: my console says: GET http://localhost/[%22%7Bcategory:%20'Novi/u010darski%20portal',%20value:%201%7D%22] 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: so that's the error. you need to make sure your server returns the correct data before even thinking about drawing it!

Comment: yeah but if I run PHP it gives me valid JSON, no problems...